# How to recursively get an array of child ids in Modx Revolution without using getChildIds

Tags: mysql, modx-revolution

getChildIds can be very slow if running it against a large set of resources, so I am trying to write a query and some code to get all the child ids faster.

However I am getting different results from getChildIds & my script.

Can anyone see why these would be yielding different results?

Method using getChildIDs:

```
$parentDepth = isset($scriptProperties['parentDepth']) ? $scriptProperties['parentDepth'] : 5;

$parents = explode(',', $parents);

$children = array();

foreach ($parents as $parent){

    $ids = $modx->getChildIds($parent,10,array('context' => 'web'));

    foreach($ids as $id){

        $children[] = $id;

    }


}

echo ' number of children = ' . count($children);
```

method using queriees & a loop:

```
$comma_separated = implode(",", $parents);

$sql = "SELECT `id` from modx_site_content where `parent` IN  (".$comma_separated.") and  published = 1 and isfolder = 0 and deleted = 0 and hidemenu = 0;";

$results = $modx->query($sql);

$mychildren = array();

while ($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {


    $mychildren[] = $row['id'];

}


for($i=0; $i <= 10; $i++){

  $comma_separated = implode(",", $mychildren);

  $sql = "SELECT `id` from modx_site_content where `parent` IN  (".$comma_separated.") and  published = 1 and isfolder = 0 and deleted = 0 and hidemenu = 0;";

  $results = $modx->query($sql);

  while ($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {


      $mychildren[] = $row['id'];

  }
}

echo ' number of children = ' . count($mychildren);
```

The getChildIDs method takes nearly 1.5 seconds to run and gives about 1100 results

The SQL/script method runs un under 0.1 second and gives 1700 results.

Either I'm not appending the child ids to the array properly ~or~ maybe getChildIDs is filtering out some other results?

does anyone have any clues as to what could be happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code again, the discrepancy in results is pretty obvious now. I'm appending results to the child id array, it's inserting duplicates since one parent can have many children.

the solution to avoid duplicates:

```
$mychildren[$row['id']] = $row['id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [built-in method of pdoFetch](https://github.com/bezumkin/pdoTools/blob/master/core/components/pdotools/model/pdotools/pdofetch.class.php#L990-L1027).

```
$pdo = $modx->getService('pdoFetch');
$ids = $pdo->getChildIds('modResource', 0);
print_r($ids);
```

It also recursive, but can be better in some situations.
Of course, you need to [install pdoTools](http://modx.com/extras/package/pdotools) from the repository first.

Answer (score -1):

[getChildIds](https://github.com/modxcms/revolution/blob/master/core/model/modx/modx.class.php#L726) - is recursive, so it slower by default.

Comment: @ vasis & bezumkin The whole idea here is to not use the modx bloated methods - that looping query above runs in less than 1/10th  the time it takes getChildIds. This particular instance we are dealing with more than 6000 resources things like getResources, getChildIds etc get way too slow with that much data to parse through.